# Automatic flavor detection with ml_flow load_model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mlflow

I am using mlflow and want to handle different flavors (e.g. `sklearn` , `tensorflow` and `keras`) while loading.

Actually I only find the information about the stored `flavor` as string in

```py
Run.to_dictionary()['data']['tags']['mlflow.log-model.history']
```

output:

```py
[{"run_id": "8ea47843f7b446828dbd9cd3a1ed2339", "artifact_path": "model", "utc_time_created": "2022-04-26 10:39:55.639791", "flavors": {"keras": {"keras_module": "tensorflow.keras", "keras_version": "2.7.0", "save_format": "tf", "data": "data", "code": null}, "python_function": {"loader_module": "mlflow.keras", "python_version": "3.8.10", "data": "data", "env": "conda.yaml"}}, "model_uuid": "3bd37bdb0aa1409aabc65f8314018642", "mlflow_version": "1.25.1"}]
```

Run is the `mlflow.entities.Run` object.

Using `ast.literal_eval` to transform the string into the dictionary fails.

```py
ast.literal_eval(str(self.run.to_dictionary()['data']['tags']['mlflow.log-model.history'][1:-1]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [mlflow.pyfunc](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pyfunc.html) says:

> The python_function model flavor serves as a default model interface for MLflow Python models. Any MLflow Python model is expected to be loadable as a python_function model.

This means you can use `mlflow.pyfunc.load_model`  to load all mlflow supported flavors.